# What command do I upgrade my angular 1.x version to the last 1.x version?

Tags: angularjs, npm, npm-install

First, I am unsure how checking the version of Angular because if I type the command, "Angular -v" it says "Angular: command not found". I think someone told me that it was version 1.5, but I want it to be 1.6 or whatever the latest angular 1 version is available to upgrade.

Lastly, what is the command to update the version to the latest version of Angular 1.x? Is it, "npm install [NAME OF ANGULAR 1.X PACKAGE]"?

Comment: There is no command. You shouldn't try to upgrade the version if you don't know what AngularJS even is, and how to program an AngularJS application.

Comment: JB Nizet, you cant say if I don't know what AngularJS is or not. You should know already that there are various major releases of Angular  there are 1, 2, 4 and now 5. Surely there is command to upgrade subversions as I can easily find that there are major version updates that can be done with easy to find commands.

Comment: Well, you seem to think it's a command line tool: "if I type the command, "Angular -v" it says "Angular: command not found". So now you at least know that it's not a command line tool.

Comment: I cant find the command to upgrade angular subversions anywhere on google. If I can't update the Angular subversions through the CLI how do I do that?

Comment: No, there is not. Upgrading is a complex programming process, consisting in reading the changelog to be prepared and know what will have to be changed, knowing what modules of the framework are used, what third-party libraries are being used and need to be upgraded, check if they're compatible with the new version, understanding the dependency management system(s) being used, if any, changing/downloading the new versions, Adapting all the code that needs to be, run the tests, etc. All that needs a thorough understanding of the code and its architecture. It's not just a command to execute.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you letting me know that.

Comment: If your project uses `npm` for module management, you can upgrade to a specific version using `npm uninstall angular; npm install angular@1.6 --save`

Comment: Thanks lofihelsinki. I have npm for module management and that is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the npm update as per the npm documentation:

https://docs.npmjs.com/all

You can run an npm outdated first to see what is in need of updating and then run the npm update, but some combination in the command prompt of...

```
npm update
npm outdated
```

... should at least get you started.

As for your version of angular somewhere in your project you have to have the angular source code thaht will include the license version, or a link to a cdn or the like for it. Maybe search the project for something like "license AngularJS v".

The uninstall/reinstall works too, but you might need to do it for more than just the angular package. Even with the update method it is likely that you'll need to look into dependencies and other packages that will become outdated.